# Is flight recorder a sampling based or an instrumentation based profiler?

Tags: java, jvm, jfr

I couldn't find this info despite having looked at flight recorder documentation? I was basically looking to record all of the execution of my program and not even lose a single small function because of sampling.

Comment: If you sample every method, your recording will be highly inaccurate as it will be spending all it's time on the most called methods even if they are trivial. Instrumentation can be 10-100x slower and about the same for inaccuracy if you are not careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFR):

> JFR continuously saves large amounts of data about the running system. This profiling information includes **thread samples** (which show where the program spends its time), lock profiles, and garbage collection details.

(Emphasis added.)

Generally speaking, instrumentation is somewhat expensive, so if you see a tool that promises very low/no overhead, you can be pretty sure it's sampling.

Comment: Are there any open source instrumentation based profilers for jdk?

Comment: I'm not sure offhand, sorry. Questions asking for tool recommendations are off topic at Stack Overflow, but you could try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. That said, I imagine this is something a Google search would also be able to answer. If you want free for non-commercial software and don't care about open source, try VisualVM.

Comment: @yshavit why do you say “[if] don't care about open source”? Isn’t VisualVM GPL software?

Comment: @Holger I wrote that comment on my phone and didn't know for sure at the time -- should have specified that in my comment. Looks like you're right, and it's GPL2, too.